# rest api direct vs nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, cors

I am a newbie in nginx and CORS and finding it challenging getting this right.

I have rest services hosted on a server which blocks CORS so installed nginx to proxy for rest call.  What works:

1. rest api call (from angular code) to backend server after enabling CORS
2. rest api call (from chrome) to frontend nginx server which has cors enables

What doesn't work: rest api call (from angular code) to frontend nginx

I think the CORS part work as I do not see that error anymore but angular is getting a null response.

For above scenarios, I have tried using GET and POST methods. Response code is 200 OK even for failed scenario.

Here is the nginx conf:

```
upstream myserver {
    server      myserver.com:8443;
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name  myserver.com;
    ssl_certificate     /some.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /some.key;

    location /rest-service/ {
        # Simple requests
        if ($request_method ~* "(GET|POST)") {
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
        }

    # Preflighted requests
    if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD";
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
      return 200;
    }

        proxy_pass_header       Server;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_connect_timeout   5;
        proxy_read_timeout      240;
        proxy_intercept_errors  on;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass                      https://myserver/rest-service/;
        proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate   /some.pem;
        proxy_ssl_verify                off;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse         on;

    }
}
```

Here is the angular/typescript code (running from loaclhost):

```
  ngOnInit() {
    let url='https://myserver.com/rest-service/login?login=admin&password=password';
    this.http.get(this.url).subscribe((response) => {console.log(response); });
  }
```

Comment: Which browser you have tried?

Comment: You need to use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54956629/edit to edit/update teh question and add the complete details about the request and response: What headers is your frontend code adding to the request? Is the request that you get a null response for an OPTIONS request? What’s the HTTP status code of the response? What are the exact error messages the browser is logging in the devtools console?

Comment: In addition to the comment from @sideshowbarker - please include the javascript where you compose the request.

Comment: thank you for the response, I have added all those details.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the issue and posting it here; hope it helps someone.

Following worked:

> ```
>     if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
>         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:4200' always;
>         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
>         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Accept' always;
>         add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
>         add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
>         add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
>         return 204;
>     }
>     if ( $request_method = 'GET' ) {
>         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:4200' always;
>         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
>         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Accept' always;
>         add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
>     }
>     if ( $request_method = 'POST' ) {
>         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:4200' always;
>         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
>         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Accept' always;
>         add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
>     }
> ```